# True or false: if $f'(x)<0$, for all real numbers $x$, then $f$ decreases without bound.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine whether the following statement is true or false. If $f'(x)<0$, for all real numbers $x$, then $f$ decreases without bound.

Answer (score 4):

**False.** Consider $f(x)=e^{-x}$. Observe that $f'(x)=-e^{-x}<0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Yet since:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}=0
$$
we know that $f$ is decreasing but is bounded below by $0$.

Comment: Thank you!!! you are a STAR.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider this plot of $f(x)=e^{-x}$:

[image]